# Accessing JWT-token in flask-sockets while using it with flask-restful

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-socketio

I am able to get the **jwt token** for the get, post, put requests using **get_jwt_identity()*.

[image]

But how can i acquire it for flask-sockets.

```
def handle_message():
    emit('message_activated', {'data': 'my data', 'count': 0})

socketio.on_event('message', handle_message)
```

Comment: There is no magic. You have to send it in the socket header from the client and parse it from the server.

Comment: I was sending the access token while doing the axios request, but I don't know how to pass headers to socket event

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the JavaScript Socket.IO client, you can use the `extraHeaders` option to pass custom headers. Example:

```js
var socket = io("http://localhost:5000", {
  extraHeaders: {
    "X-My-Auth": "your-token-here"
  }
});
```

Of course you can replace the `X-My-Auth` header name with the header that you are using.

In the server, authentication for Flask-SocketIO events is performed only when the client connects. There is no need to authenticate every single event because there is a permanent connection between the client and the server. Here is an example connection handler:

```py
@socketio.event
def connect():
    token = request.headers['X-My-Auth']
    if not verify_token(token):
        return False
    # user is authenticated, proceed normally from here on
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a class-based namespace for sockets.
Create a decorator to validate the token that is shared by the client. I am using the `permission.py` file to define the decorator.

> permission.py

```
from flask_socketio import Namespace, emit


    def requires_authentication(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            token = request.headers.get("Authorization")
            if not token:
                emit(
                    "data_fetched",
                    "token is missing",
                    namespace="/ws/active-alarms",
                    # broadcast=True,
                )
            is_valid = validate_token(token)
            if not is_valid:
                emit(
                    "data_fetched",
                    "token is expired",
                    namespace="/ws/active-alarms",
                    # broadcast=True,
                )
    
        return wrapper
```

> Socket.py

```
class DummyData(Namespace):

    @requires_authentication
    def on_connect(self):
        print("********connection establised*************")

    def on_disconnect(self):
        print("********closing the connections*************")

    @requires_authentication
    def on_fetch_data(self, pagination_data):
        error = {"code": 500, "message": ""}
        try:
            # your logic
        except Exception as e:
            message = str(e)
            error["message"] = message
            emit(
                "data_fetched",
                error,
                namespace="/ws/active-alarms",
                # broadcast=True,
            )
```

> JS

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:5000", {
  extraHeaders: {
    "Authorization": "your-token-here"
  }
});
```